# Does Salesforce1 support custom buttons?

Tags: custom-button, salesforce1-app

We have created a custom button on the `Opportunity` object.  It is viewable, and works fine in regular Salesforce, but when I go into `Salesforce1`, I can no longer see the custom button.

Is this just a problem with my instance, or does `Salesforce1` not support custom buttons?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Salesforce1 doesn't support custom buttons, but you might consider moving that button's functionality to a Publisher Action, which is supported in both the web GUI and in Salesforce1. (This is assuming your custom button is a detail button.)

Publisher Actions are clearly SFDC's preferred method for adding capabilities to a a record detail page going forward.

Comment: That's what I was a afraid of.  This leads to another question I have.  My button is an OnClick Javascript button.  Would the best practice be to Make a publisher Action with a Custom visualForce page as the Action, and put my Javascript into that VisualForce page?

Comment: It's hard to say, without knowing what your javascript button is trying to accomplish. (As an aside, I wonder if the fact that it's a javascript buttonmight explain why it's not showing up for you in SF1 when you convert it to a link.) My suspicion is that a VF page with your javascript on it will not work, but I can't be sure.

Comment: Yeah... I just checked, and It is because It was an OnClick Javascript button

Comment: [@MattWelch, @LShropshire] but i have a custom button with javascript content source code exists. now do i need to create a new action? how to assign that OnClick Javascript button this new action?  please give me some steps to assign that custom button to nuw action, Please guide me asap  Thanks

Answer (score 12):

I do want to point out the following.

Custom buttons do seem to work in the following scenario: (I have 2 of these buttons in my current project)

- custom button
- display type : detail page button
- content source : visualforce page

These DO show up in Salesforce1 when adding them to the page layout.

So in this case, the on-click javascript functionality could be moved to a visualforce page (nicer anyway) and that should work.

Answer (score 11):

As noted, Salesforce1 does not support custom buttons. However, Salesforce1 does support Custom Links. You can get the same functionality as your custom button, but it will be displayed at the bottom of your page. If you change your `Detail Page Button` to a `Detail Page Link` and add it to your Page Layout, it should appear at the bottom of the record in the Custom Links section.

**EDIT:** For the sake of completion, I do go back and verify that On-Click Javascript Detail Page Links do not work. When I switched back to URL, it immediately displayed.

Comment: I tried doing this and It still worked fine on web GUI, but I still couldn't see it on Salesforce 1.  On SF 1, I didnt even see a Custom Links section.

Comment: That is odd. I don't think I did anything special in my Dev org to get that to work. I'll research it a bit more and make sure I don't have something special checked off.

Comment: It was because I was using an Onlick Javascript button/link

Comment: Ah, I guess that does make sense. Glad you found a solution.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is possible to have custom buttons in Salesforce1 detail page section.
Following the [Salesforce1 App Guidelines](http://sfdc-styleguide.herokuapp.com/assets/S1AppGuidelines.pdf) it should be possible.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Old question but the latest answer. It might be helpful if someone landed on this page looking for solution as I did today. From Spring'16 release, Salesforce supports custom buttons in SF1. From the [Spring'16 release notes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring16/release-notes/rn_forcecom_general_url_button_support_lex.htm):

> Custom buttons and links that define their **content** **source** as **URL** are
>   now supported in Lightning Experience and the Salesforce1 mobile app.
>   This feature was previously available in Salesforce Classic only.

Answer (score 1):

We have custom buttons on List Views and have created VisualForce Pages (specifically for Salesforce1) that display those list views and the custom buttons (for example, we created a button to update a custom field that our external sales team uses to make reporting more accurate).  Otherwise, I've created publisher actions like everyone else mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE IN SALESFORCE (SPRING'16)**

Custom Buttons and Links (URL redirects) are fully supported in both the mobile web and app versions of Salesforce1 if their "Content Source" is a Visualforce page or a URL from after Spring '16.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000187793&type=1